# SQLite trigger to delete record that activated the trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a trigger in order to delete a record 2 minutes after it has been created. This will be used in a 'recover password' scenario so those 2 minutes will be the time window for someone to use the validation code to recover their password. SQLite is what I am working on. Here's the situation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS password_recovery(
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    confirmation_id INTEGER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users (email)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
);

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS password_recovery_deletion_timer AFTER INSERT ON password_recovery
    BEGIN
       DO SLEEP(120);
       // i want to delete here but how do I pass which record triggered the trigger?                
    END;
```

Comment: I would consider this a *very* dangerous operation.

Comment: Why not store both an expiration date and the hash in an associated table. Then just check that the users hash matches, and that the expiration date is greater than the present

Comment: atoms I think this is where i am going eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a (primary) key of the table:

```
DELETE FROM password_recovery WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
```

However, triggers are executed as part of the statement that triggered them. So the original INSERT statement would wait for two minutes, and the login would not be able to read this row from the database because the insert transaction would not have finished yet.

The only correct way to implement this is to make the recovery request and the recovery two separate transactions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using references like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwit-M_vubrPAhWC6YMKHUcfDkcQFgg6MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3resource.com%2Fsqlite%2Fsqlite-triggers.php&usg=AFQjCNEndRhsbeu41VhLxwJ5wfE02LkJgg&sig2=0WrO7VFAhHNx2UackX1jRA)
or [this one.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwit-M_vubrPAhWC6YMKHUcfDkcQFghBMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sqlitetutorial.net%2Fsqlite-trigger%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJWebx0rFWIf-ZwihyMdJj39iEng&sig2=FKPDtyD48kr3gk5jm0IfpA)

May both be able to help you in your case. You code to me seems to have some issues as well, look into that. You must create a trigger for that trigger, similarly shown in the links I've provided.